# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'header'

Tags: spring, spring-security, header

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">



    <http pattern="/login.html" security="none">
        <headers></headers>
    </http>

</beans:beans>
```

This is my spring-security.xml file. I am getting the below error while deploying in server.

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 12;
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element

```
'{"http://www.sringframework.org/schema/security":headers}'. One of '{
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":intercept-url, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":access-denied-handler, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":form-login, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":openid-login, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":x509, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":jee, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":http-basic, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":logout, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":session-management, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":remember-me, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":anonymous, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":port-mappings, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":custom-filter, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":request-cache, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":expression-handler}' is expected.
```

Could you please anyone help on this error?

Comment: Which version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: Spring Security version is 3.1.1 Release. I tried to update 4.0.0 version and more.. But still I am getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `<headers>` tag was added in Spring Security 3.2. As the error message explains, in Spring Security 3.1 `<headers>` is invalid content in the `<http>` block. It is expecting one of `<intercept-url>`, `<access-denied-handler>` etc

Please be aware that Spring Security 3.x and 4.x have reached the end their supported life so, ideally, you should upgrade to Spring Security 5.x. At the time of writing, Spring Security 5.2.x, 5.3.x, 5.4.x and 5.5.x are the supported generations.

If you are stuck on Spring Security 3.1, then you cannot use the `<headers>` tag.